# how to add where clause in formtype symfony2

Tags: forms, symfony, include

its been days now that am looking for the 'how' of this problem. I just learned symfony2 and i cant find a way to this, i've tried different stuff found on the net but i could not get any to work.

Here is my problem, I have a form PictureType in which i include another entity Collection (which is a collection of picture or if you prefer an album of picture).

When the user uploads his picture he needs to select in which album he wants to put it.

My problem is that I cant figure out how to tell in my PictureType to select ONLY the collections of the current user.

here is my pictureType

```
 $builder
        ->add('file')
        ->add('collection', 'entity', array(
            'class' => 'AppPictureBundle:Collection',
            'property' => 'name'
            ));
```

I want to insert after property something like this

Where 'user_id' = $this->getUser()

I have a manyToOne on Collection target User and a ManyToOne on picture target collection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There [the `query_builder` option](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html#query-builder) for that:

```
$builder
    ->add('file')
    ->add('collection', 'entity', array(
        'class' => 'AppPictureBundle:Collection',
        'property' => 'name',
        'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
            return $er->createQueryBuilder('c')
                ->where('c.user = :user')
                ->setParameter('user', $this->getCurrentUser());
        },
    ));
```

Comment: hi Elnur, i've tried this

    $user = $container->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();

     ->setParameter('user', $user);
but I am having an error 500 and i need to restart wamp to be able to load any page !!